# Rails associations with self joining class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, self-join, nomethoderror

I doing a rails project where I'm using a self joining one-to-many setup.

I have a class called User, which has many customers.
Each customer has many order lists, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'owner_id'
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :order_lists, dependent: :destroy
```

Now when I opened my rails console. I tried to do this:

```
user.customers.order_lists
```

I got this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `order_lists'
```

While when I try to do this:

```
user.customers.first.order_lists
```

I do receive the order lists of that customer.
But how could I recieve all the orderlists of all my customers?

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all order_lists for all customers associated with a user?

This will do the trick:

```
user.customers.map(&:order_lists).flatten
```

Or you could make a scope on OrderList that takes a set of customer_ids like so:

```
scope :for_customer_ids, ->(customer_ids) {
  where("user_id IN (?)", customer_ids)
}
```

And then

```
OrderList.for_customer_ids(user.customer_ids)
```

Comment: This solutions works in the console, but I want to display my orderlists. So when I want to paginate them this doesn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: I don't see a solution other than: OrderList.find(user.customers.map(&:order_list_ids).flatten. And this is building on the previous answer

Comment: I think you could write a scope on OrderList in order to use pagination.

Comment: I solved it like this:  OrderList.page(params[:page]).where('user_id IN (?)', current_user.customers.map(&:id).flatten).order('users.username ASC,name ASC').includes(:user) Doesn't look beautiful, what's your opinion?

Comment: You don't need to call flatten. Also, you can call customer_ids rather than customers.map(&:id).

Answer (score 1):

In a has many relationship when you call:

```
user.customers
```

it returns an array of all the customers the user "has", so when you are calling

```
user.customers.order_lists
```

`order_lists` is being called on an array of customers. (which doesn't have the method `order_lists`). The first method gives you the first customer in the array so it will work. You could also do something like:

```
user.customers[0].order_lists
```

if you wanted. (using first is better though)

Getting the order_lists of all customers would be to loop through all customers and get them like that.